# ZF + Doctrine2 phpUnit error: PDOExeption: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, doctrine-orm

I'm using DynamicGuys doctrine2 integration into zend framework(https://github.com/dynamicguy/zf1doctrine2).
It works, but if i want to make tests with phpUnit i get this error:
    PDOExeption: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances

I've searched a bit, and i found out that if i comment out line 44 in this file:
https://github.com/dynamicguy/zf1doctrine2/blob/master/library/ZendX/Doctrine2/Application/Resource/Entitymanagerfactory.php phpUnit works, but of course the rest of the application wont work, as the entity manager wont be returned

Any ideas on where the error comes from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has something to do with PHPUnit backuping globals and static attributes between each tests. If you have a PDO instance it will break up when trying to serialize. I ran into a similar issue and I could not find where the PDO instance was stored as a global parameter, but disabled the backupGlobals and backupStaticAttributes in the needed test did the trick for me.

```
/**
 * Search test.
 *
 * @backupGlobals disabled
 * @backupStaticAttributes disabled
 *
 * @author Steven Rosato
 */
class SearchControllerTest extends \Majisti\Test\TestCase
{
    ...
}
```

source: http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/797-Global-Variables-and-PHPUnit.html

Comment: So disabling this, doesnt affect the tests in any way?

Comment: Well according to the source I provided, if you have globals that affect other tests it will, but if you don't have globals that make tests dependent to them, it should run just fine.

Comment: Ok, so i actually have to do this in each testfile :(

Comment: You add it to the phpunit configuration xml file. Or from the command line pass the --no-globals-backup flag